# script.sh: line 1: ./gradlew: No such file or directory on Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

This is error message I got

> ./gradlew clean assembleRelease
>   /Users/bhanukaisuru/.jenkins/workspace/OrelGo@tmp/durable-b74adbad/script.sh:
>   line 1: ./gradlew: No such file or directoryPipeline Script

Pipeline Script

```
stage('Build Release APK') {
             sh "./gradlew clean assembleRelease"
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to specify the Jenkins workspace with the commands `sh` and `bat` if you want to execute a command on the root level of it.

`sh 'mkdir test'` would create a folder in `<jenkins_workspace>/test` for example.

If `gradlew` is located on the root of the Jenkins workspace the following should be sufficent:

```
sh "gradlew clean assembleRelease"
```

otherwise a full path works as well.

Comment: not working... ````/Users/don/.jenkins/workspace/demo@tmp/durable-e05b533d/script.sh: line 1: gradlew: command not found```

Comment: Where is 'gradlew' located? Of course you have to be in the directory of it.

Comment: this project is a flutter project, not a native android. there is not gradlew file in Jenkins project location.

Comment: This won't work if it is not located in the Jenkins workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You should CD to where your gradlew binary folder is, or using full path of the gradlew. because the command you run is executed in epemeral directory, not in the jenkins home. you can use ${JENKINS_HOME} to use the path of your jenkins home