# flutter command not found on Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, flutter, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I successfully installed Flutter on my local pc. But when add to Jenkins, said `flutter command not found`

**Pipeline script**

```
stage('Build Release APK') {
            //  sh 'export PATH="$PATH:/Users/bhanukaisuru/Documents/flutter/bin"'//after said, flutter command not found I added this line, but not working
              sh "flutter clean"
              sh "flutter build apk --split-per-abi"
         }
```

Before Adding Flutter command, I added this line.

```
sh "./gradlew clean assembleRelease"
```

also said, gradlew not found

Comment: Is this the same question as you asked before? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60129590/script-sh-line-1-gradlew-no-such-file-or-directory-on-jenkins/60135427?noredirect=1#comment106375963_60135427

Comment: yes. but this is releated to Flutter

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the path of flutter in environment within your stage like this:

```
    environment {
        flutter = "/Library/Flutter/bin/flutter"
    }
    steps {
        sh '$flutter clean'
    }
```